# PDF Pages Included, but it does't work

Tags: pdfpages

I am writing my thesis, and I need to add a single `pdf` page in the appendix, so I found a way to use the `pdfpage` package. Normally I added the package, when I added the package and I continued writing it up. and when I compiled, I could not see any changes to my document. it basically blocks everything. when I delete that line (`\include{PdfPackage}`} then everything works fine. it didn't even append the pdf page.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{ecsthesis}  
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Comment: Think of this question from the community's perspective. You need to provide more information in order to solve this. Apart from having a *crystal ball* there's not enough information to adequately answer this. How about creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem, and including the `.log` file of the output you receive as part of your question (via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/71463/edit)).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my apologies for lack of information. I am writing my thesis, and I need to add a single pdf page in the appendix, so I found a way to use the pdfpage package. Normally I added the package, when I added the package and I continued writing it up. and when I compiled, I could not see any changes to my document. it basically blocks everything. when I delete that line (\include{PdfPackage}} then everything works fine. it didn't even append the pdf page.

Comment: You include the package with `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and include the PDF with `\includepdf{file.pdf}`, right? If its only a single page, you actually don't need to use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). You could just use [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and `\includegraphics[page=X]{file}`. However, then you might have to do some jigging with the scaling of the page. Regardless, that can be done...

Comment: Yes, you are right, Yes I will try with include graphics. But the pdf page is landscape, is it possible to turn it into portrait as the document is portrait.

Comment: Yes, see the [`graphicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf). `\includegraphics[page=X,angle=90]{file}` or even `\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[page=X]{file}}`.

Answer (score 5):

If the included page is in landscape, then it should probably rotated, when viewed in the PDF reader. Package `pdflscape` notifies the PDF viewer by setting a rotation angle for the pages in environment `landscape`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
% ...
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% ...

\begin{document}
Hello World.

\begin{landscape}
\includepdf[angle=90]{t.pdf}
\end{landscape}

End of document.
\end{document}
```